# Adding config options to JUJU bundles

Tags: juju

Hi I want to deploy a bundle and my `bundle.yaml` looks like this:

```
series: trusty
services:
  testcharm:
    charm: "./trusty/testcharm"
    num_units: 1
    to:
      - "0"
  neo4j:
    charm: "./trusty/test_neo4j"
    num_units: 1
    to:
      - "1"
relations:
  - - "neo4j:db"
    - "testcharm:db"
machines:
  "0":
    series: trusty
    constraints: "arch=amd64 cpu-cores=1 cpu-power=100 mem=1740 root-disk=8192"
  "1":
    series: trusty
    constraints: "arch=amd64 cpu-cores=1 cpu-power=100 mem=1740 root-disk=8192"
```

Now I need to change my `config.yaml` of my testcharm because of an option I added that is different in every model. Is there a way to add a config option for a specific service in a bundle so It gets deployed with that option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `options:` in your `bundle.yaml` to add specific config values for a specific charm.

```
series: trusty
services:
  testcharm:
    charm: "./trusty/testcharm"
    num_units: 1
    to:
      - "0"
    options:
      config-option: "config value"
  neo4j:
    charm: "./trusty/test_neo4j"
    num_units: 1
    to:
      - "1"
    options:
      port: "7474"
relations:
  - - "neo4j:db"
    - "testcharm:db"
machines:
  "0":
    series: trusty
    constraints: "arch=amd64 cpu-cores=1 cpu-power=100 mem=1740 root-disk=8192"
  "1":
    series: trusty
    constraints: "arch=amd64 cpu-cores=1 cpu-power=100 mem=1740 root-disk=8192"
```

I edited the `bundle.yaml`. If there was a `port` options in your neo4j `config.yaml` you can overwrite that value by using options like in the bundle above.